# Can a user commit to a documentation proposal if their best answers is zero scored

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-proposals

In trying to garner support for a Documentation Proposal against a fairly niche tag, I'm using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to identify potential committers through the following [Potential Documentation Proposal Committers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523974/potential-documentation-proposal-committers) query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(u.DisplayName) AS [User Name], 
    'http://stackoverflow.com/users/' + LTRIM(STR(MAX(a.OwnerUserId))) AS [Profile URL], 
    MAX(u.LastAccessDate) AS [Last on Stack], 
    MAX(u.Reputation) AS Reputation, 
    MAX(a.Score) AS [Highest Score], 
    SUM(a.Score) AS [Total Score]
FROM 
    Posts AS a
INNER JOIN
    Posts AS q
    ON q.Id = a.ParentId
INNER JOIN
    Users AS u
    ON u.Id = a.OwnerUserId
WHERE 
    q.Tags LIKE N'%visual-studio-lightswitch%' AND 
    a.PostTypeId = 2 /*Answer*/ AND
    a.Score > 0 /*With at least 1 positively scored answer - could this be >= 0?*/ AND
    u.Reputation >= 150 /*Must have 150 reputation*/ AND
    DATEDIFF(month, u.LastAccessDate, GETDATE()) < 18 /*Active on SO in the last 18 months*/
GROUP BY
    a.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY
    MAX(u.Reputation) DESC
```

However, I'd just like to clarify if an answer with a score of [zero is regarded as positive or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26705/77100) in the context of meeting the following commit criteria:

> With at least 1 positively scored answer

Comment: You can `SELECT Users.Id as [User Link]` to get nice user links.

Comment: @Squidward That's neat, thanks.  As this is my first foray into using the data explorer, can you recommend any good pages covering tips like this?

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, zero doesn't count as positive in this case. `a.Score > 0` is correct.